# Getting the error message 'Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.' when trying to install rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

Running the command `pip install rpy2` results in the following output and error message:

```
Collecting rpy2
Using cached rpy2-3.5.12.tar.gz (217 kB)
Installing build dependencies ... done
Getting requirements to build wheel ... error
error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [28 lines of output]
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "c:\users\97254\working_project\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 353, in <module>
        main()
      File "c:\users\97254\working_project\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 335, in main
      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs'])
      File "c:\users\97254\working_project\venv\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pyproject_hooks\_in_process\_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
        return hook(config_settings)
      File "C:\Users\97254\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-b21o8iu5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel
        return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel'])
      File "C:\Users\97254\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-b21o8iu5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires
      self.run_setup()
      File "C:\Users\97254\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-b21o8iu5\overlay\Lib\site-packages\setuptools\build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup
      exec(code, locals())
      File "<string>", line 124, in <module>
      File "<string>", line 110, in get_r_c_extension_status
      File "./rpy2/situation.py", line 295, in get_r_flags
      _get_r_cmd_config(r_home, flags,
      File "./rpy2/situation.py", line 255, in _get_r_cmd_config
      output = subprocess.check_output(
      File "C:\Users\97254\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 420, in check_output
      return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
      File "C:\Users\97254\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 501, in run
      with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
      File "C:\Users\97254\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 947, in __init__
      self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
      File "C:\Users\97254\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\subprocess.py", line 1416, in _execute_child
      hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
    FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified
    [end of output]

  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: subprocess-exited-with-error
```

I uninstalled and reinstalled R and associated directories according to directions on another Stackoverflow post, and got the same error. I also tried installing a previous version of rpy2 and got the same error.

If anyone has an idea how to resolve this error I'd be glad to get it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

try

```
pip install wheel
```

or install rpy2 from github repo instead of PIP

Comment: I already have it installed. I uninstalled and reinstalled it and got the same error when trying to install rpy2.

Comment: pip3 install wheel setuptools pip --upgrade

try this

Comment: Still the same error.

Comment: there is issue raised in Github repo about this .[link](https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2/issues/1028) ,  Try installing from the Github source rather than pip

Comment: Are you referring to a zip file that can be downloaded from github?
Should I unzip it and put it in the python project's site packages?

Comment: clone the github repo , and in  that repo folder 
type "python setup.py install"

Comment: It seems to work (didn't run the script yet). Thanks.

Comment: After cloning the repository, I need to transfer rp2 directory to the site-packages? I didn't get to use GitHub cloning much.

Comment: Windows support is still patchy. R is likely not in the PATH when running pip. Uninstall rpy2, then try with `pip install -v --no-cache-dir rpy2`. The early logs printed to the terminal should give clues about what is happening.

Answer (score 2):

I did this as some one said above ..
*pip3 install wheel setuptools pip --upgrade*

then it told me I had to install by specific use eg ..
*pip3 install azure-identity*
as pip install azure was deprecated .

see https://azure.github.io/azure-sdk/releases/latest/all/python.html

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34970531)

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I downloaded a zip file of rpy2 from [rpy2's GitHub page](https://github.com/rpy2/rpy2), unzipped and placed it in the python project's site-packages, which enabled using the package.

Answer (score 0):

For me what I did was just change the version number of the affected library to the latest version released.